# Obter valor da segunda célula quando encontrou a primeira

Tags: javascript, tabela-html

Olá gostaria de saber se alguém consegue ajudar no seguinte?
Tenho um campo input com um valor.
Tenho uma tabela com 2 campos (campo 1 e campo 2)
Quero percorrer a tabela e se encontrar no campo 1 o valor igual ao campo input então devolvo o valor do campo 2 dessa linha

```js
function obterCampo2(e){
var valor = $("#campoinpu").val();
//com valor percorrer todos as tr (os primeiros td) e se houver igual ao valor do input devolver o segundo td dessa linha;
// se o input for 8000825071492 vai devolver 30.0000
$.each($('#percorrertabela table tbody tr'), function() {
  var x = this;
  console.log(x);
});
}
```

```css
table {border: 1px solid red;}
thead {background: black;color:white;}
tbody tr td {border: .5px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="campoinput" class="form-control" onclick="obterCampo2(event)">

<div id="percorrertabela" class="tableFixHead">
  <table>
    <thead><tr><th>campo1</th><th>campo2</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>8000825411007</td><td>1.0000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>8000825018800</td><td>10.0000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>8000825019609</td><td>10.0000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>8000825071201</td><td>1.0000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>8000825071492</td><td>30.0000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>8000825966453</td><td>100.0000</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer o que você precisa poderia ser:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="campoinput" class="form-control"> <input type="button" value="Obter campo 2" onclick="obterCampo2()">

<div id="percorrertabela" class="tableFixHead">
  <table>
    <thead><tr><th>campo1</th><th>campo2</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>8000825411007</td><td>1.0000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>8000825018800</td><td>10.0000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>8000825019609</td><td>10.0000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>8000825071201</td><td>1.0000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>8000825071492</td><td>30.0000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>8000825966453</td><td>100.0000</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function obterCampo2(){

  let valor = $("#campoinput").val();
  
  $.each($('#percorrertabela table tbody tr'), function() {
    let linha = $(this);
    
    let colunaCampo1 = linha.children().first().text();
    let colunaCampo2 = linha.children().first().next().text();
    
    if(valor == colunaCampo1){
        console.log(colunaCampo2);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: obrigado @Alisson Acioli resultou mudando pequenas coisas.

Answer (score -2):

Não sei se entendi corretamente a sua pergunta, mas parece que você está tentando buscar um valor dentro da tabela através do valor digita dentro do seu input. Se for isso vamos a algumas considerações:

1. Adicionar um botão de pesquisa e associar ele ao evento click, ao invés de associar ele ao input com o valor que o usuário irá digitar:

Isso aqui:

```js
<input id="campoinput" class="form-control" onclick="obterCampo2(event)">
```

Var virar isso:

```html
<input id="campoinput" class="form-control" /> <input type="button" id="pesquisar" onclick="obterCampo2()" />
```

2. Na função `obterCampo2()`, basta você comparar os valores percorridos dentro do loop `$.each` com o valor do campo que você digitou:

Isso aqui:

```js
function obterCampo2(e) {
  var valor = $("#campoinpu").val();
  //com valor percorrer todos as tr (os primeiros td) e se houver igual ao valor do input devolver o segundo td dessa linha;
  // se o input for 8000825071492 vai devolver 30.0000
  $.each($('#percorrertabela table tbody tr'), function() {
    var x = this;
    console.log(x);
  });
}
```

Vai virar algo como isso:

```js
function obterCampo2() {

  $.each($('#percorrertabela table tbody tr td'), function(i, v) {

    var valorCapturadoDoInput = $("#campoinput").val();

    if ($(v).text() == valorCapturadoDoInput) {
      alert("valor encontrado: " + $(v).siblings().text());
    }

  });
}
```

*Note que eu usei a função [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) que busca o elemento irmão ao que você está comparando ( td ), por isso consegui trazer o valor ao invés do número da primeira coluna*

*Existem formas melhores de fazer isso, essa é apenas uma tentando não alterar muito a sua estrutura do seu código*

[Você pode ver o exemplo funcional aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/jLx6nf7t/2/)

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação @William a sua resposta também estava correta